# Remove all element in the linkedlist that is great than a user input value at runtime

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to delete all elements from the linked list which are greater than the user input value which user will enter.At present i am having the following code.Consider i am having 5 elements in the list already like 12,23,34,45,56.Now if i enter 20 in the output i want output as 12.I am able to delete last element of linked list.But i want to delete all elements which is greater than user input value at runtime.

Here is LinkedList.java

```
    import java.io.*;
    class node
    {
    int data;
    node prev,next;
    public node(int x)
    {
    data=x;
    next=null;
    }
    }
    class SLL
    {
    node start=null;  
    public int removeLast()
    {
    if (isEmpty())
    {
       System.out.println("empty");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        node current=start;
          while (current.next.next!=null)
            current=current.next;
        int x=current.next.data;
        current.next=null;
        return x;   
    }
   }
   public int removeAllBasedOnInputValue(int val){

   //I dont know how to implement code here//

   }

   public void display()
   {   
   if (isEmpty())
   System.out.println("The list is empty");
   else
   {
    node current=start;
    while (current!=null)
   {
    System.out.print(current.data+" ");
    current=current.next;
   }
   }
   } 
   public class Sl 
   {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
   InputStreamReader obj=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
   BufferedReader r=new BufferedReader(obj);
   int ch;
   SLL s=new SLL();
   do
   {
        System.out.println("1.Remove");
        System.out.println("2.Display");
        System.out.println("3.Exit");
        System.out.println("Enter your choice:");
        ch=Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
        switch (ch)
        {

    case 1:
                System.out.println("1.Remove tail");
                System.out.println("2.Remove all elements based on specific value");
                System.out.println("Enter choice:");
                int al1=Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
                switch (al1)
                {

        case 1:
                    System.out.println("deleted: "+s.removeLast());
                    break;
        case 2:
            //System.out.println("deleted:"+s.removeAllBasedOnInputValue();
            break;

                }
                break;

    case 2:
                s.display();
                break;
    case 3:
                break;
        }
}while(ch!=3);
}
```

}

At present i am able to remove element at the last that is the tail.It is working fine.But i dont know how to implement logic for deleting all elements which are greater than input value that i am providing during runtime.Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help:

```
public int removeAllBasedOnInputValue(int val){
    if (isEmpty())
    {
       System.out.println("empty");
        return 0;
    }else{

        int counter=0;
        node current=start;

        //here we will go to the last node
        while(current.next != null){
            if(current.data > val){
                /* Here, we need to verify 3 things:
                * 1 - If it is the start;
                * 2 - If it is the end; and
                * 3 - If it is the body.
                */

                /*1st verification - 
                If the start is bigger than your value,
                then you just make your next node as "start",
                and make its previous as NULL.*/
                if(current == start)
                {
                    start = current.next;
                    current.next.prev = null;
                }/*2nd verification - 
                If it is the last element,
                then you just make the next node of your previous be NULL.*/
                else if(current.next == null)
                {
                    current.prev.next = null;
                }/*3rd verification - 
                You will make the next of the previous as your current next; 
                and the previous of the next as your current previous. 
                In that way you will lose all the ways of reaching the current 
                (which is greater than the value)*/
                else
                {
                    current.prev.next = current.next;
                    current.next.prev = current.prev;
                }
                counter++;
            }
            current.next = current.next;
        }

    return counter;
    }
}
```